# How to convert ImageString to Image Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-templates, django-views

I am recieving my image string from  android  using Asynchttp and well i want to convert that image string to an Image in Django Rest Framework..Just convert it not to store it in an ImageField

***Model.py**

```
class Food(models.Model):
label=models.TextField(max_length=200)
link = models.FileField(null=False, blank=False)
Image = models.TextField(link, null=True)

 class Android(models.Model):
label=models.TextField(max_length=200)
imagestring=models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)  //convert this to Image
```

***Serializer.py**

```
class AndroidSerializers(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):   
class Meta:
    model = Android
    fields = ('label', 'imagestring')



 class FoodSerializers(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
 class Meta:
    model=Food
    fields=('url','label','Image','link')
```

***Views.py**

```
class FoodViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = Food.objects.all()
serializer_class =FoodSerializers

class Androids(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset =Android.objects.all()
serializer_class = AndroidSerializers()
```

Comment: what do you mean by image string, is it base64 encoded string ??

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention it..Yes it is an base64encoded string

Answer (score 0):

You can use PIL library to deal with strings, images and vice-versa.

```
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import base64
im = Image.open(BytesIO(base64.b64decode(data)))
```

To use it in serializer, create a custom field

```
class ImageSerializerField(serializers.Field):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        return value # convert it the way you want to see in json
    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        im = Image.open(BytesIO(base64.b64decode(data)))
        return im
```

```
class AndroidSerializers(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    imagestring =  ImageSerializerField() 

    class Meta:
        model = Android
        fields = ('label', 'imagestring')
```

Ref : https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#custom-fields

> https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/
>   https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow

Comment: how to use this in our serilizer class?